# Tenho um script que eu insiro o numero de meses e me retorna a data do prazo final. Mas preciso diminuir um dia do resultado

Tags: javascript, funções, data, if, matemática

Dev's boa tarde!

Estou tentando criar um script que calcule a data final a partir de uma data inicial e seu prazo em meses. Ex:

Data inicial: 01/08/2018
Prazo: 60 meses
Data final: 31/07/2023 (60 meses - 1 dia)

```
function calcDate() {
  var dat = document.getElementById("data").value;
  var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
  if(dat != "" && meses != "") {
    var sp = dat.split("/");
    dat = new Date(sp[2], sp[1]-1, sp[0]);
    var m = meses%12;
    var y = Math.floor(meses/12);
    var tmp = dat.setMonth(dat.getMonth()+m);
    var tmp = dat.setYear(dat.getFullYear()+y);
    var f = new Date(tmp);
    document.getElementById("final").value = ("0" + f.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (f.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Boa tarde Pedro, legal que está tentando, posta aí o que já fez até então.

Comment: Caro Pedro, entenda uma coisa, não somos um site de serviços gratuitos de TI, você esta pedindo algo bem especifico que teria que ser desenvolvido, e não é o que fazemos aqui, aqui o que fazemos é ajudar a concertar scripts, apontar soluções de APIs e explicar sobre tecnologias, terminologia. Da forma que a sua pergunta esta é como se você esperasse que alguém realmente fosse fazer tudo para ti, então recomendo que reformule a pergunta, apresente o que tentou e leia o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help ... Temos regras e recomendações, se segui-las vai conseguir obter melhores resultados.

Comment: @LeAndrade, editei a postagem para mostrar até onde eu fui. Mas ainda estou tentando...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado! Se a pergunta não for pertinente estarei deletando... Mas só queria informar que sou iniciante e estou buscando ajuda como forma de estudo.

Comment: Consegui com ajuda de um amigo criar a função que gera o data final. O que estou quebrando a cabeça agora é onde eu preciso alterar para que a data diminua um dia, ficando assim o prazo correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após a variável `f`

acrescente essa linha `f.setDate(f.getDate()-1);`

**Veja exemplo funcionando**

```js
function calcDate() {
  var dat = document.getElementById("data").value;
  var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
  if(dat != "" && meses != "") {
    var sp = dat.split("/");
    dat = new Date(sp[2], sp[1]-1, sp[0]);
    var m = meses%12;
    var y = Math.floor(meses/12);
    var tmp = dat.setMonth(dat.getMonth()+m);
    var tmp = dat.setYear(dat.getFullYear()+y);
    var f = new Date(tmp);
    //diminui 1 dia da data
    f.setDate(f.getDate()-1);
    document.getElementById("final").value = ("0" + f.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (f.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="01/08/2018"/>
<input type="text" name="meses" id="meses" value="60"/>
<input type="text" name="final" id="final" value=""/>
<button type="button" onclick="calcDate();">Calcular</button>
```

**Outra forma:**

```js
function calcDate() {
  var dat = document.getElementById("data").value;
  var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;

//Inicialmente formatamos a data para new Date(ano, mes, dia);
partes=dat.split("/");
var myDate=new Date(partes[2],partes[1]-1,partes[0]);
//data final + 60 meses
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+parseInt(meses));
//data final - 1 dia
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()-1);

var dia=myDate.getDate();
var mes=(myDate.getMonth()+1);

//dia e mes com dois digitos
dia = (dia.toString().length == 1)?'0'+dia:dia;
mes = (mes.toString().length == 1)?'0'+mes:mes;

//data final
newDate = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + myDate.getFullYear()

document.getElementById("final").value=newDate;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" value="01/08/2018"/>
<input type="text" name="meses" id="meses" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="final" id="final" value=""/>
<button type="button" onclick="calcDate();">Calcular</button>
```